# jQuery(document).ready and passing '$'

Tags: jquery, wordpress, document-ready

I have a js file that I am including in my Wordpress template. Is there a way to get access to the '$' function inside my 'MediaBrowser' object without having to clumsily pass it around as an argument?

Thanks,
Steve

```
var MediaBrowser = {
    initialize:function($){
        $("a[rel^='mediaBrowser']").prettyPhoto();
    }   
};
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    MediaBrowser.initialize($);
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: Maybe check your acceptance rating you would get more answers for your questions if you give feedback to those that were already answered.

Comment: @tadman: Probably for the same reason jQuery has a `.noConflict` method? I would say it's safe to assume they're using `jQuery` explicitly for a reason, but would like the ability to use the `$` short-hand and not have it interfere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var MediaBrowser = {
    initialize:function(){
        var $ = jQuery; //local var or just use `jQuery` below
        $("a[rel^='mediaBrowser']").prettyPhoto();
    }   
};
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    MediaBrowser.initialize();
});
```

Comment: Ah, I ended up just going with ading the $=jQuery; to the .ready function above the initialize. Thanks @Neal

Answer (score 3):

Use a self-invoking function to get access to jQuery via $.  There are many reason you'd want to do this so don't listen to other people telling you to just access it globally...

```
var MediaBrowser = (function($) {
  return {    
    initialize:function(){
      $("a[rel^='mediaBrowser']").prettyPhoto();
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some conflicts somewhere? You could create a closure for MediaBrowser. Keep in mind, it will need to execute after jQuery has loaded.

```
var MediaBrowser = function() {
    var $ = jQuery;

    return {
        init : function() {
            // blah jquery stuff using $(..) syntax
        }
        ...
    }
}();
```

Comment: I guess Wordpress dynamically loads jquery in no conflicts mode. I'm new to WP and jquery (coming off of prototype). Thx for the sugg.

Answer (score 0):

Could always wrap in an anonymous function (but then, due to scope, you'd need to explicity make the `MediaBrowser` part of the `window`:

```
(function($){
    window.MediaBrowser = {
        initialize: function(){
            $('<p>').text('Sample').appendTo('body');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    MediaBrowser.initialize();
});
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. I guess I didn't want to have to make it part of the window object. Went super simple above.